# PyroCMS 404 when trying to run "installer" URL on MAMP

Tags: php, mamp, pyrocms

I'm trying to install PyroCMS on MAMP 5.2

I've created a directory for the installation at `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/pyrocms` then used Composer to install it:

```
composer create-project pyrocms/pyrocms
```

Composer completes without giving any errors.

When I navigate to the "public" directory at `http://localhost:8888/pyrocms/pyrocms/public/` it tries to redirect to an "installer" URL (`http://localhost:8888/pyrocms/pyrocms/public/installer`) then gives the following 404 error:

> The requested URL /index.php was not found on this server.

There is no directory called "installer" inside "public" (i.e. `public/installer` doesn't exist in the filesystem). I assume it's trying to use some kind of rewrite condition to run an installer but can't see what it's supposed to be executing.

How can I fix or debug this?

I've followed the installation instructions as given at https://pyrocms.com/documentation/pyrocms/3.4/installation/installing-pyrocms

Using PHP version 7.2.10

Comment: Try to install it from the command line with `php artisan install` command. Btw, I'd better use PHP 7.1 for it. It seems you have wrong server config.

Comment: You might try using `php artisan serve` to serve your application instead of MAMP. The installer is a system addon (you'll see it in the 'core' directory) and uses a route provided by the addon service provider.